# Is it possible to filter a p:dataTable when filterBy is a List of Objects?

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm using the component p:dataTable from Primefaces and I'm having a trouble to sort a list of objects.

I have a list of Emails and inside this list I have an other list with their email alias. This is my code:

```html
public class Email {

    private String idGoogle;
    private String email;

    public Email() {
    }

    public Email(String idGoogle, String email) {
        this.idGoogle = idGoogle;
        this.email = email;
    }  
    
    public String getIdGoogle() {
        return idGoogle;
    }

    public void setIdGoogle(String idGoogle) {
        this.idGoogle = idGoogle;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
 }
```

```html
public class EmailSector extends Email implements Cloneable {

    private Sector sector = new Sector();
    private String password;
    private String domain;
    private String description;
    private List<Email> aliasList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EmailSector> emailSectorList = new ArrayList<>();


    public EmailSector() {
    }

   ...
```

```html
            <h:panelGroup id="emailsTable" >
                <div class="emailsTable" >
                    <p:dataTable id="filterTable" var="item" value="#{emailSectorBean.sessionBean.itemPagina.emailSectorList}" 
                                 widgetVar="dataWidget" 
                                 emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado com os dados buscados.">

                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.email}" headerText="E-Mail" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                  filterValue="#{emailSectorBean.sessionBean.filtroAlteracao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.email}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.description}" headerText="Descrição" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.description}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.sector.description}" headerText="sector" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.sector.description}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Alias" filterBy="#{item.listaAlias}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:dataTable var="alias" value="#{item.listaAlias}" >
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alias.email}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </h:dataTable>
                        </p:column>                        
                    </p:dataTable>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

At this point:

```html
                        <p:column headerText="Alias" filterBy="#{item.aliasList}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:dataTable var="alias" value="#{item.aliasList}" >
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alias.email}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </h:dataTable>
                        </p:column>
```

I print all the alias of an Email Sector. The problem is the type of aliasList is Email... So I would like to know if it's possible to use filterBy with a List and how can I got this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by overriding the toString method, just like this:

```html
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.email;
    }
```

And then I called the toString method in the filterBy attribute:

```html
<p:column headerText="Alias" filterBy="#{item.aliasList.toString()}" filterMatchMode="contains">
   <h:dataTable var="alias" value="#{item.aliasList}" >
      <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{alias.email}"/>
      </p:column>
   </h:dataTable>
</p:column>
```

It worked fine!